# Deselect all radio values in Oracle Forms (12C)

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracleforms

How could I deselect all the values from radio group in Oracle Forms 12c?

I put

```
:BLOCK.RADIO_ITEM := NULL;
```

It raise error "FRM-40212: Invalid value for field RADIO_ITEM."

Should I add a dummy hidden radio button with value 'X' under :BLOCK.RADIO_ITEM.  Put

```
:BLOCK.RADIO_ITEM := 'X';
```

try to look like deselect all the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed all of the radio items within a spesific radio group can't be deselected. But a workaround might be considered through hiding one of the `Radio Button` witihin a `Radio Group`.

As an example, add a `Radio Group` of Number data type having three `Radio Buttons` (namely `Radio_Button0`, `Radio_Button1`, `Radio_Button2`) with `Functional->Radio Button Values` `0`, `1` and `2` respectively. And then set `Physical->Visible` property of `Radio_Button0` to `No`. That's don't use this Radio Button by any means.

This way all of the members of our Radio Group will appear as deselected in Runtime.